# Error got for required name parameter must be provided in flutter at flatbutton

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart-pub

This is my code for xylophone making app of flutter program in android studio.

[image: code part:1]

[image: code part:2]

And my pubspace.yaml file code is

[image: yaml code]

And output is

[image: error]

And i want output like this

[image: want Output]

I try many type of github,stake overflow,quara and flutter.dev solution.
clear cashes,restart.
lettest version with flutter sdk path.

Comment: press `Ctrl + q`

Comment: Try pressing ctrl + space